# How to set a variable string with a float value in datafactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following value:

"Value": 8.371582

but I have to assign it to a string variable, how can I do it

Comment: Hi @willy sepulveda,  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concern, please feel free to let me know, thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you get any progresses?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you get the value to set the variable. I tested and the value "8.371582" can be assigned to the variable successfully.

For example, I create a string variable `aa`:
[image]

Set the variable value "8.371582":
[image]

Run this active and check the variable value:
[image]

In Data Factory, the float or other data type will be converted to String automatically if the variable type is set as String.